# How to cancel the call to the input () method in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem.

In a client system, when a client sends a message, it is attached to a queue to answer messages one by one.

Now if the client that is being serviced disconnects you should read and reply to the next message. The probelema is that when the client disconnects the system is waiting for the entry of text in the `input` for example:

```
Received: Customer Message 1
Reply to client 1:> Message from client2 #If client 1 disconnects
```

What is expected is that this `input` is skipped so that it does not wait for the response to a client that has already left and a result like this remains:

```
Received: Customer Message 1
Reply to customer 1:> # Customer 1 left
Received: Customer Message 2
Reply to client 2:> Message to client 2
```

server.py

```
import socket
import threading

class Hilo1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,Funcion,Funcion2,cliente,direccion):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.Funcion = Funcion
        self.Funcion2 = Funcion2
        self.Cliente = cliente
        self.Direccion = direccion

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.Funcion(self.Cliente,self.Direccion)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            self.Funcion2(self.Cliente)


class Servidor_C():
    def __init__(self):

        self.ListaUsuarios = []
        self.ListaMensajes = []

        self.Escucha()

    def EliminarUsuario(self,cliente):
        self.ListaUsuarios.remove(cliente)
        for elemento in self.ListaMensajes:
            if elemento[1] == cliente:
                self.ListaMensajes.remove(elemento)
                self.LeerMensaje()

    def LeerMensaje(self):
        while self.ListaMensajes:
            for i,mensaje in enumerate(self.ListaMensajes):
                print("\n",mensaje[0])
                resuesta = input("> ")
                print("\n",mensaje[1],"--","nuevo conexion")
                mensaje[1].sendall(resuesta.encode())
                self.ListaMensajes.remove(self.ListaMensajes[i])


    def RecibirMensaje(self,cliente,direccion):
        while True:
            mensaje = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
            self.ListaMensajes.append([mensaje,cliente,direccion])
            if len(self.ListaMensajes) == 1:
                threading.Thread(target=self.LeerMensaje).start()

    def Escucha(self):
        servidor = socket.socket()
        conexion = ("192.168.8.5",500)

        servidor.bind(conexion)
        servidor.listen(2)

        while True:
            cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()
            self.ListaUsuarios.append(cliente)
            Hilo1(self.RecibirMensaje,self.EliminarUsuario,cliente,direccion).start()

Servidor_C()
```

client.py

```
import socket

conexion = ("192.168.8.5",500)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)

while True:
    linea = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(linea.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(respuesta)
cliente.close()
```